# psycopg2.DataError: integer out of range

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models, psycopg2

Thanks in advance for the help. I am new to Django, and trying to use postgres for my database.

When I try to migrate my Django models, the following error shows up:
[psycopg2.DataError on line 85 of django/db/backends/utils.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFEyY.png)

[django.db.utils.DataError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkfko.png)

I originally was using MariaDB and there were no problems. 
[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFgVk.png)
Also, my models.py file currently has the models that I wish to use commented out.
Here is my [database configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvCgN.png) as well.

Thanks

Comment: show your model and replace images on text.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the post to include what I currently have as models.py. Can you please clarify what you mean by replace images on text